# How to calculate expected risk from fitted Cox PH model in R?

Tags: r, survival, expected-value, cox-model, risk

I'd like to calculate expected risk (cumulative incidences), which are derived from fitted Cox PH model using R packages.

I have the fitted Cox PH model like as follows:

> **[Variables]**
>    Dataset: 10,000 cases(patients) with 6 variabels
>
> t: time to event, s: event (coded as 0 or 1)
>
> covariates: X1, X2, X3, X4 (coded as 0 or 1)
>
> > fit <- coxph (Surv (t,s) ~ X1+X2+X3+X4, data=data)
> >
> > summary (fit)
> >
> > > ```
> > >        coef   exp(coef)  se (coef)   z     P         
> > > X1   -0.3777   0.6855   0.1120   -3.37   0.00075
> > > X2    0.4014   1.4938   0.0518    7.74   <0.0001
> > > X3    0.7417   2.0995   0.0893    8.31   <0.0001
> > > X4    0.4330   1.5419   0.1268    3.42    <0.001
> > > ```

From this model, I'd like to calculate expected risk (cumulative incidence of events) for each cases according to X1 = 0 or X1 = 1.

## In other words, if the X1 of all 10,000 cases were 0, how could I calculate expected risk for each cases? At the same time, if the X1 of all 10,000 cases were 1, how could I calculate expected risk for each cases? (using R)

## After calculating the expected risk for each patients, then I'd like to calculate the risk-benefit ratio for each patients according to variable X1 [by (Expected risk, when X1 = 0) - (Expected risk, when X1 = 1)], dose it right?

Meanwhile, I have tried to plot the expected cumulative risk curve according to X1 like as follows; was it appropriate ?

> > baseha = basehaz (fit, centered=FALSE)
> >
> > > ```
> > > X1=0: exp (-0.38*0) = 1, X1=1: exp (-0.38*1) = 0.68
> > > ```
> >
> > plot (baseha$$time[,2], baseha$hazard*(1), type="s", lty=1)
> >
> > lines (baseha$$time[,2], baseha$hazard*(0.68), type="s", lty=2)

Thanks for your kind answers.

Comment: Is this a programming question?  If so, you might be better served on Stack Overflow, although you may get an answer here too.

Answer (score 1):

To derive risk estimates from a Cox model you typically use the Breslow estimator for the cumulative baseline hazard that is coupled with the hazard ratios from the Cox model. This is implemented in the `survfit()` function of the **survival** package. In particular, if you give as a first argument your fitted Cox model, and in the `newdata` arguments you specify a data frame with the specific values for the covariates `X1`, $\dots$, `X4`, you get survival probabilities, which you can transform to risks by calculating 1 - Survival.